# Pyspark Streaming - display starting window only from [window_start, window_end]

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am reading a list of csv files in as a stream and bucket the timestamps using 1 hour intervals.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

stream = streaming.selectExpr("car", "cost", "timestamp")\
        .withWatermark("timestamp", "30 seconds")\
        .groupBy(F.col("car"), F.window("timestamp", "1 hour").alias("tmst_window"))\
        .agg(F.sum("cost").alias("agg_cost")) 

    +--------------+------------------------------------------+------------------+
    |car           |tmst_window                               |agg_cost          |
    +--------------+------------------------------------------+------------------+
    |Toyota        |[2010-12-01 14:00:00, 2010-12-01 15:00:00]|10                |
    |Ford          |[2010-12-01 14:00:00, 2010-12-01 15:00:00]|20                |
    |Audi          |[2010-12-01 13:00:00, 2010-12-01 14:00:00]|30                |
```

How do I display it instead using only the start window, and exclude the end window timestamp? I want to  get the results in real time, so I don't want to store it to a temporary dataframe and then split/explode the data. How would the streaming query above be rewritten to produce the below instead?

```py
    +--------------+--------------------------------------+------------------+
    |car           |tmst_window                           |agg_cost          |
    +--------------+--------------------------------------+------------------+
    |Toyota        |2010-12-01 14:00:00                   |10                |
    |Ford          |2010-12-01 14:00:00                   |20                |
    |Audi          |2010-12-01 13:00:00                   |30                |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print out the of `stream` you will notice that the column `tmst_window` is a struct type with elements `start` and `end`:

```
root
 |-- car: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tmst_window: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- start: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |-- end: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- agg_cost: double (nullable = true)
```

Therefore, you can select the start element with something like `F.col('tmst_window')['start']` or, even easier, `F.col('tmst_window.start')`